# Species identification: fizzing plants

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, aquatic-plants

Many years ago I added some plants to my aquarium that would bubble aggressively from their leaves. When the lights were turned up high they would almost fizz. My angelfish liked to swim in the bubble stream.

The ribbon-like leaves spiraled up the stem (vaguely like a spiral staircase). They were bright green and about 1 centimeter in width. The stalks themselves quickly grew to the top of my tank, so they were about a foot and a half high.

I've never been able to rediscover what type of plant it was.

Comment: The bubbling is often called 'pearling' in the hobby because they look like shiny pearls coming off the plants.

Answer (score 4):

There is an aquatic plant called Ludwiga inclinada or curly tornado, that matches your description. I added a pic, although it may not be what you're remembering. I was originally thinking it was a type of sword, possibly Vesuvius Sword Plant, but with leaves seems wider than described, the second and 3rd pics are the Vesuvius Sword.

[image: Curly Tornado Ludwiga]

[image: Vesuvius Sword]

[image: Also ves.sword]

Answer (score 2):

The most vigorous oxygenator I have seen is *Vallisneria*, which also comes as "corkscrew". Although other plants, like hornwort (*Ceratophyllum*) may exhibit scattered oxygen bubbles, the vascular system of the *Vallisneria* may concentrate it producing a steady stream of bubbles.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a plant named African elodea (*Lagarosiphon muscoides*). It is a good oxygenating plant.

Another similar plant is American/Canadian waterweed (*Elodea canadensis*).
This one does live in the wild where I live. We call it water pest (vass pest in Norwegian) as it can take over an entire pond in a short time. It is a very good oxygenating plant.

There is also the Brazilian water weed (*Egeria densa*). This is often used as an oxygenating plant in fish tanks.

If you put any of these plants in a glass jar with water and place it in sunlight, it starts to bubble oxygen within a very short time.

If one has an algae problem these plants are the solution, but be aware these plants are banned in some countries as they can spread like wildfire if only a tiny piece of the stem ends up in the wild.